# Use of use jQuery.getJSON() for a Url

Tags: jquery, json

How i use jQuery.getJSON() to obtain data for this URL?

http://gbrds.gbif.org/registry/organisation/a3c228d0-3110-11db-abb8-b8a03c50a862.json?op=contacts

If i look the result in a browser, i get this result:

```
[{"position":"","lastName":"","phone":"+39 06 6118286","type":"technical","city":"","country":"","isPrimaryContact":true,"postalCode":"","address":"","email":"m.skofic@cgiar.org","description":"","province":"","firstName":"Milko Skofic","salutation":"","key":"48"},{"position":"","lastName":"","phone":"39-06-6118204","type":"administrative","city":"","country":"","isPrimaryContact":true,"postalCode":"","address":"IPGRI, Via Tre Denari, 472/a, 00057, Maccarese, Rome, Italy,","email":"eurisco@cgiar.org","description":"","province":"","firstName":"Ms. Sonia Dias","salutation":"","key":"49"}]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference in result from $.ajax json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752905/difference-in-result-from-ajax-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method on the jQuery documentation.

The sintaxe:

`$.getJSON(url, data, function success);`

So, you can try something like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://gbrds.gbif.org/registry/organisation/a3c228d0-3110-11db-abb8-b8a03c50a862.json?op=contacts", null, function(data) {


      // loop in your result if it is an array
      $.each(data, function(i, item) {

         // use data[i].property to access each property of your array.
         // for sample:

         var p = data[i].position;
         var l = data[i].lastName;

      });​

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are requesting the URL from a different schema/host/port combination (e.g. `https://gbrds.gbif.com:8080`) your browser will throw a security exception because of a violateion of the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

One way around this would be if you could implement [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) which jquery also supports.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JSONP because it's not on the same domain.

```
$.getJSON("http://gbrds.gbif.org/registry/organisation/a3c228d0-3110-11db-abb8-b8a03c50a862.json?op=contacts&callback=?", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```